# Capturing rtspsrc headers in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, rtsp, python-gstreamer

I'm looking to get the [Timestamp header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7826#section-18.53) from RTSP payloads using the python gstreamer bindings.
Based on my understanding of the rtspsrc component, what I want is to attach a callback to the [handle-request](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtsp/rtspsrc.html?gi-language=c#rtspsrc::handle-request) signal, such that when it arrives I can [inspect the headers](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/rtsplib/gstrtspmessage.html?gi-language=c).
This is well and good, I thought I knew how to attach a listener:

```py
...

def callback(*args):
    """As dumb a callback as can be: just send to stdout whatever you see."""
    print(args)

...

rtspsrc = Gst.ElementFactory.make('rtspsrc', 'component')
print(f"Connecting callback: {rtspsrc.connect('handle-request', callback)}")

...
```

print shows that I'm successfully attaching the signal (and I'd get a TypeError if the signal didn't exist). But I start the connection, I watch data stream through, and my callback never fires.

What am I missing?